# Google Translate Drop Down

Tags: web, translate

i have purchased a website template and i need help concerning the website translator using google translate.
The translate works well but after selecting a language, a google drop down appears and when i scroll down, it still appears and hides my main header titles.
Can something be done like removing this drop down when i translate a language or can someone suggest me another method.
Thanks a lot.
[image: The Drop down highlighted in red]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the the contents in this bar are inside of an iframe, So you cant use javascript to trigger the close button.

**Solution**

Once the user chooses a language the an iframe with a class  named 'goog-te-banner-frame'
is added.

You can use javascript to detect if it present and hide it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.goog-te-banner-frame').length > 0){//check if the iframe exsits
            $('.goog-te-banner-frame').css('display','none');
            $('body').css('top',0);//google adds top to the body so the bar wont cover website content
    }
});
```

because this code uses jquery. make you sure you load it like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey BinaryGhost i really appreciate your help.
I am putting the code into <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
where should i place it?

Comment: It did not work, i placed in the <head> and in the language <div> section.

Comment: did you load jquery? i have updated the answer the be more clear